# 6-letter strings from the word APPLES where L comes before E?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the word APPLES. How many 6-letter strings are possible such that the L appears to the left of (but not necessarily next to) the E?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $$\left(\frac{6!}{2!}\right)$$ to make six-letter words. Divide by two to find the number of words in which L is to the left of E. So, the answer is $$\frac{\left(\frac{6!}{2!}\right)}{2} = 180$$

Comment: Small corection, It should be $\left( \frac{6!}{2!} \right)$ and not $\left(\frac{6}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 4):

In total, there are $\frac{6!}{2!}$ arrangements of these six letters (we divide by $2!$ since there are two letters P). Half of these have the L to the right of the E, and half of them have the L to the left of the E.

Answer: $\frac{6!}{2\cdot 2!}=180$.

Comment: How do you know that half have the L to the right of the E and half of them have the L to the left of the E?

Comment: There is a trivial bijection between "arrangements with L to the left of E" and "arrangements with L to the right of E", so they must be equally many.

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose the two places for the L and E, and then 
$\frac{4!}{2!}$ ways to arrange A,P,P,S in the remaining 4 places; so there are
$\binom{6}{2}\cdot\frac{4!}{2!}=15\cdot12=180$ ways in total.

Comment: Nice solution user84413.

Answer (score 1):

Total Permutation is 6!/2 in which half has E left to L and other half L left to E so the answer is 6!/4=180